# Can't Filling DropDownList with Ajax in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Everything seems OK but value shows empty..
I have 2 dropdownlist, when I choose first one, I got the index and used ajax to fill other dropdownlist.. But problem is that I dont have result.. loop that is in ajax, doesnt work.. and I checked web tool of firefox, result seems empty, but in C# code, the list has items..

so here is my ajax

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("ElectionList", "Home")",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { electionTypeId: selectedId },

        success: function (data) {


            if (data != null) {
   //HERE IS WORKING
                alert("OK");

                electionCombo.html('');
                $.each(data, function (index,item) {
     //here is not working !!! 
                    alert("hobaaa: " + index);  
                    alert("data: " + item.Text);
                    //    alert(option.ID + "  " + option.politicName);
                    //  electionCombo.append($('<option></option>').val(option.Value).html(option.Text));
                });

            }
```

here is my c# code

```
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult ElectionList(int electionTypeId)
    {


        var service = new EvoteServicesProviderClient();


        try
        {
        var electtionType = service.getAllElectionTypes().FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == electionTypeId);

           var  res =
                service.searchElectionByType(electtionType.electionTypeName)
                    .ToList()
                    .Where(e => e.startDate >= DateTime.Now)
                    .Select(e => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = e.ID.ToString(),
                        Text = e.politicName
                    });


            var list = new SelectList(res, "Value", "Text");
            return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

         //   return Json(new { success = true, result = list },
           //      JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 

        }
        catch{}

        return Json(new { success = false, message = "An error occured" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

this is the html side

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ElectionList", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", id = "electionlistform"}))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedElectionId, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedElectionId, Model.ElectionList, new {@class = "form-control", id = "electionList"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedElectionId)
}
```

As I wrote, the list is not empty (in actionresult ElectionList)

What I am missing?

Comment: Please post the rest of the code... Where is `electionCombo` defined?

Comment: Why are you creating a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` then converting that to a `SelectList` (both are unnecessary)? Just return an collection of anonymous object containing `e.ID` and `e.politicName`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie,    var electionCombo = $("#electionList");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$.each(data, function () {
 //here is not working !!! 
                alert("hobaaa: " + this.Value);  
                alert("data: " + this.Text);
 });
```

You can access the property directly because it's json.

**UPDATE**

Just return the list server side :

```
var  res =
            service.searchElectionByType(electtionType.electionTypeName)
                .ToList()
                .Where(e => e.startDate >= DateTime.Now)
                .Select(e => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = e.ID.ToString(),
                    Text = e.politicName
                });


                return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: As @py3r3str said, there no need to use a SelectList. You can and should use anonyme type when returning json

Comment: What's in data before the loop ? alert(data[0]);

Comment: Does res as something in it server side before returning ?

Comment: No, firstly ElectionList works, after i got the ajax success.. But actually i dont understand your question

Answer (score 1):

What I do when I need to fill a dropdown is the same as you, but I'm using a for loop instead of each (maybe it's the same but for me it's working). And by the way, in your ajax code sample you are not closing the ajax function. Hope in your real code it's okay.

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("ElectionList", "Home")",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { electionTypeId: selectedId },

        success: function (data) {


            if (data != null) {
   //HERE IS WORKING
                alert("OK");

                electionCombo.html('');
                for (i in data) {
                    var result = data[i];
                    //  electionCombo.append($('<option></option>').val(result.Value).html(result.Text));
                }

            }
   });
```

By the way, if it's still not working , you could try a ViewModel with the options you need

```
public class ViewModelExample
{
    public Int32 ValueOption { get; set; }
    public String TextOption { get; set; }
}
```

And use it in your list instead of selectlist. With viewmodels I don't have problems getting the values with json.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i solved it with code above. :)